# javascript getUserMedia get media stream time

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, getusermedia

How can I obtain a current stream time of the stream object in javascript ?

`navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
  .then(function(stream) {
      console.log("get stream time here")
})`

Is there any possible way to get stream time ??

Answer (score 4):

You can get the *playback* time using [currentTime](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/currentTime) (use [fiddle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/currentTime) to make getUserMedia work):

```js
var wait = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

(async () => {
  video.srcObject = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true});
  while (true) {
    console.log(video.currentTime);
    await wait(100);
  }
})().catch(e => console.log(e));
```

```html
<video id="video" width="160" height="120" autoplay></video><br>
<div id="div"></div>
```

There is no inherent stream time without hooking it up to a sink and playing it. E.g. if you join a WebRTC video call late, there's no stream time that tells you when the meeting started.

Comment: Note that different browsers appear to interpret currentTime for MediaStreams differently.  In Chrome I see times which increment with each frame from a webcam.  In Firefox I get different behaviour, currentTime increments more frequently.  So in Chrome I can extrapolate the true framerate of the webcam, in Firefox I can't.